# Сгруппировать значения из полей в список через запятую

Tags: sql

Задание:

Название машины покажите полное, с названием бренда — например: Tesla Model 3.

Отсортируйте по имени пользователя в восходящем порядке. Сортировка внутри самой строки с машинами не нужна.

Comment: `group_concat` есть там в СУБД ?

Comment: `string_agg` видимо

Comment: судя по заданию, у вас там должна быть таблица клиентов, таблица продаж, таблица машин и таблица брендов. надо все это добро заджойнить, бренды с машинами сконтактенировать, а потом группировать по юзеру с агрегацией полученных названий через запятую

Comment: Код(Включая SQL), необходимо прикладывать текстом к вопросу. Очень желательно прикладывать структуру таблиц и подготовленные insert данных. Тогда ответ может быть быстрее и точнее.

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода значений из полей в качестве списка, используется функция [STRING_AGG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

> STRING_AGG(ПОЛЕ, РАЗДЕЛИТЕЛЬ)

Для того, что бы вывести список продавцов и проданных авто, нам надо сгруппировать(**GROUP BY**) таблицу по продавцам, а в качестве агрегирующей функции указать **STRING_AGG**

```
select person_name person, STRING_AGG(auto, ',') cars 
from brandorigin
group by person_name
order by person_name ASC;
```

[песочница dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xux3gUqd)

Comment: @xflx Не понимаю... Надо видеть структуру и данные которые там лежат + желаемый результат. Лучше всего это делать в песочнице, например [https://dbfiddle.uk/](https://dbfiddle.uk/). Если в одном поле лежит несколько значений, можно попробовать применить функции поиска и возврата подстрок. [Можно поискать в доках](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). Попробуйте самостоятельно с новыми знаниями, не получится, сделайте новый вопрос, добавив всю необходимую информацию + ссылку на песочницу, что бы можно было на ваших данных поиграться